# what is a path called that visits every vertex of a graph at least once?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, hamiltonian-path

As I understand it, a Hamiltonian path visits every vertex of a graph exactly once. Is there a name for a path which visits every vertex at least once?

Some graphs may be such that a cycle visiting every vertex, must visit some vertices more than once. I'd like to talk about the shortest such cycles.

Comment: I have not an answer, but you may refer to [this topic](https://en.google-info.org/691898/1/graph-theory.html).

Comment: A path that you describe will exist if and only if the graph is connected. However, I couldn’t find a *name* for such a path.

Comment: The first pagagraph talks about **paths**, the second about **cycles**. Which is it? Does the path have to end up where it started, or not?

Answer (score 5):

A path doesn't repeat vertices by definition, so any path which does this would be a Hamilton path.

In order to allow vertices to be repeated, you should instead call it a "walk" or "trail" (the difference between the two is whether *edges* can be used more than once; in a walk they can). I would therefore call this a "covering walk". It seems this terminology has been used before: see [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493903047). However, I would define it if I was going to use it.

An alternative is "spanning walk"; see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895614000574).